# How do I return two recordcounts from an Execute SQL Task to User variables in an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got a package in SSIS 2012 that has an Execute SQL task in the control flow level.

The SQL in question does an Upsert via the SQL merge statement. What I want to do, is return the count of records inserted and records updated (No deletes going on here to worry about). I'm using the output option to output the changed recs to a table variable.

I've tried returning the values as:

```
Select Count(*) as UpdateCount from @mergeOutput where Action = 'Update'
```

and

```
Select Count(*) as InsertCount from @mergeOutput where Action = 'Insert'
```

I've tried setting the resultset to both Single rowset and Full rowset, but i'm not seeing anything returned to the package variables I've set for them (intInsertcount and intUpdatecount).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
Select UpdateCount = (Select Count(*) as UpdateCount from @mergeOutput where Action = 'Update'),
InsertCount = (Select Count(*) as InsertCount from @mergeOutput where Action = 'Insert')
```

Using a single result set this should give you an output along the lines of

```
UpdateCount | InsertCount
#           | #
```

Then just map the result set changing the name of each result and use breakpoints to test and makesure the variables update through the process.

This is what I use when I want to return multiple result sets from different tables in the same query, however I don't know how it works with the output of merge statements.

Comment: I do not see any issue with his solution. not sure why someone downvoted it.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll give it a try. But can you clarify how I map this to package variables?

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Execute SQL command** output as single line

**SqlCommand** as :

```
Select sum(case when Action='Update' then 1 else 0 end) Update_count,
sum(case when Action='Insert' then 1 else 0 end) Insert_count 
from @mergeOutput;
```

In the **Result set** tab click on the **Add** button; set your variables to point to the 2 outputs of the above query, positionally:

0 => intUpdatecount; 1 => intInsertcount